# yii how textfield input call json action

Tags: json, function, yii, action, call

I have a problem when I try to call the json action

First, in yii **_form.php**, I've got a form including a textfield to input a name, look like below:

```
<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
<?php echo $form>textField($model,'name'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
</div>
```

What I want is, when I am entering character “n”, the field implements(**calls**) actions
that I defined in an **independent json file** (e.g. index.php?r=user/getuserdata),

```
read: {
        url:"index.php?r=user/getuserdata",
        dataType: "json",
        type:"post"
      },
```

in **UserController.php**, there is an function called "actionGetUserData()",
which tells the details what this action exactly do.

```
public function actionGetUserData(){
    $amount = User::model()->findAll("1 = 1 order by id DESC"); //為了排序
    $count = count($amount); 
    for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
         $arr[$i]['id'] = $amount[$i]['id'];
        $arr[$i]['username'] = $amount[$i]['username'];
        $arr[$i]['userpwd'] = $amount[$i]['userpwd'];
        $arr[$i]['usertype'] = $amount[$i]['usertype'];
        $arr[$i]['modifytime'] = $amount[$i]['modifytime'];
        $arr[$i]['createtime'] = $amount[$i]['createtime'];
        $arr[$i]['allowip1'] = $amount[$i]['allowip1']; 
        $arr[$i]['allowip2'] = $amount[$i]['allowip2'];
        $arr[$i]['allowip3'] = $amount[$i]['allowip3'];
        $arr[$i]['allowip4'] = $amount[$i]['allowip4'];
        $arr[$i]['allowip5'] = $amount[$i]['allowip5'];

        /* $arr[$i][] = $amount[$i]->attributes; */
        /* echo "<pre>";
        print_r($amount[$i]->attributes);
        echo "</pre>"; */
    }
    $result = json_encode($arr);
    echo $result;       
}
```

In this case, let's ignore what the function exactly do (just an example). 
I want to know, how the textfield calls/triggers the getuserdata action **index.php?r=user/getuserdata** in json file.
That means how to build the relationship between textfield and json file's action.

Please tell me how to make this work in yii

**_form.php(textfield) triggers json file (action)**

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript, you can implement a function which makes an ajax to your controller actioncall based on a certain javascript event...

```
<?php Yii::app->clientScript->registerScript('makeAjaxCall',
     'function makeAjaxCall(){
         $.ajax({
             url:"index.php?r=user/getuserdata",
             dataType: "json",
             type:"post"
             /*Any Other Ajax Options here, like the beforeSend, then, done and fail callbacks*/
         })
     });?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('onblur'=>'js:makeAjaxCall();')); ?>
```

To achieve this, you can study about the [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function and the reference for [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) so you can buildthe *asynchronous call* and how your application revolves around it..